# Buzzing bees in my manor in Skyrim are driving me nuts - how do I get rid of them ... permanently?

Tags: ps3, skyrim-hearthfire

I assume there is no possible way to edit a completed manor wing built in Skyrim, and I made the mistake of adding a greenhouse wing. Now I have bees overrunning that half of the manor, and the buzzing is loud, obnoxious, and driving me nuts! Is there a possible way to eliminate them permanently? I would simply remove that wing and add a bedroom or enchanting tower, but I reckon ya only get one go 'round when you add a wing, which is really kinda idiotic this option is not made available. So I am stuck with buzzing bees unless there is a fix? Game system I use is PS3.